# Is there a way to hard reset my repo to the upstream version without typing the branch name?

Tags: git, git-reset

What I'm looking for is a way to write

```
git reset --hard origin/teamname/issue-12345-some-branch-name
```

without all the redundancy if the thing I reset to is already set as the current upstream branch.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but where's the "redundancy" exactly? What other spelling does this revision have? What I mean is: this commit has an SHA, and that SHA can have various names. You've given one of its names. What are its other names?

Comment: Try `git reset @{u} --hard`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

[`@{u}` means](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) the upstream branch for the current branch.